# 'No Column Name' when using Count function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to display the region id,  region name, and number of stores in the region for all regions with this query

```
SELECT r.regionid, r.regionname, COUNT(*),
FROM region r, store s
WHERE r.regionid = s.regionid
GROUP BY r.regionid, r.regionname;
```

The count column says "(No column name)" and I cannot figure out how to fix that

Comment: Just give it an `alias` -- `select ... count(*) as NumberOfStores from`.  Please note, no comma after the last field and the `from` statement.  Also, I would suggest using an explicit `join` over using commas in your `from` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the count column an alias.  For example, to call it "regionCount", use this:

```
SELECT r.regionid, r.regionname, COUNT(*) as [regionCount],
FROM region r
INNER JOIN store s
    ON r.regionid = s.regionid
GROUP BY r.regionid, r.regionname;
```

Answer (score 7):

Please do not use `Implicit Join`, instead use `explicit join`. You can read more about why you must not use in [*Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs*](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

```
SELECT 
   reg.regionid, 
   reg.regionname, 
   COUNT(*) as regionCount
FROM 
   region reg 
   Inner Join store st on reg.regionid = st.regionid
GROUP BY 
   reg.regionid, 
   reg.regionname;
```

And I am suggesting not use alias table like `r` or `s` why don't use `reg` for `region` and `st` for `store`.. It will help you when you make complex query become readable..

And for your `error` it's clear.. You just need to name your `count` column.